# Rails: Show action in controller is unable to access foreign key value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, rspec, controller, foreign-keys

I am attempting to build a chess application, and am testing the logic of the ability to only select pieces that match the color of the player. The method in the Piece model is passing all RSpec tests, but I run into an error while testing the show action in the pieces controller. I have narrowed down the issue to the pieces controller being unable to access the white_player_id column. It is able to access all other columns in the games table. I do not have white_player or black_player models, but I do assign the IDs based on the current_user. When a game is created, the current_user automatically becomes the white player (user.id = white_player_id), and the black player is the second user who joins the game after its creation.

How can I get the pieces controller to access the white_player_id value? I don't want to create white_player and black_player models, because they are only needed for color checks.

If it matters, the database I am using is PostgreSQL.

This is the Piece model:

```
class Piece < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :game
  validates :x, numericality: true
  validates :y, numericality: true

  scope :black_pieces, ->() { where(color: 'black') }
  scope :white_pieces, ->() { where(color: 'white') }
  scope :active, -> { where(captured: false) }


  def white?
    color == 'white'
  end

  def black?
    color == 'black'
  end

  def piece_color_matches_user_color?(user)
    if color == 'white' && user.id == game.white_player_id
      true
    elsif color == 'black' && user.id == game.black_player_id
      true
    else
      false
    end
  end

    # ...

end
```

This is the Game model:

```
class Game < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :pieces
  belongs_to :user
  before_save :start_game_when_black_player_is_added
  after_create :populate

  scope :available, -> { where(state: "pending") }

  after_create :current_user_is_white_player

  def add_black_player!(player)
    self.black_player_id = player.id
    self.total_players = 2
    save
  end

  def current_user_is_white_player
    self.white_player_id = user_id
  end

  def populate
    (1..8).each do |piece|
      pieces.create(x: piece, y: 2, color: 'white', type: 'Pawn')
      pieces.create(x: piece, y: 7, color: 'black', type: 'Pawn')
    end

    ["Rook", "Knight", "Bishop", "King", "Queen", "Bishop", "Knight", "Rook"].each.with_index(1) do |klass, index|
      pieces.create(x: index, y: 1, color: 'white', type: klass)
      pieces.create(x: index, y: 8, color: 'black', type: klass)
    end
  end
end
```

This is the User model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :games
end
```

This is the Pieces controller:

```
class PiecesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  def show
    @piece = Piece.find_by_id(params[:id])
    if @piece.blank?
      return render_not_found
    end
    if @piece.game.white_player_id # white_player_id does not exist to the controller
      # returns 404 error
    # if @piece.piece_color_matches_user_color?(current_user)
      return render plain: "Success"
    else
      render_not_found
    end
    # @game = @piece.game
    # @pieces = @game.pieces.all
  end

  def update
    @piece = Piece.find_by_id(params[:id])
    @game = @piece.game
    x_target = piece_params[:x].to_i
    y_target = piece_params[:y].to_i
    if @piece.attempt_move(x_target, y_target)
      @piece.save
    else
      return render_not_found
    end
    render plain: "Success"
  end

  private

  def render_not_found(status=:not_found)
    render plain: "#{status.to_s.titleize} :(", status: status
  end

  def piece_params
    params.require(:piece).permit(:x, :y)
  end
end
```

This is the schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20180109032015) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "games", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.boolean "finished"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "total_players"
    t.bigint "white_player_id"
    t.bigint "black_player_id"
    t.string "state", default: "pending", null: false
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.bigint "winner_id"
  end

  create_table "pieces", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "game_id"
    t.string "type"
    t.integer "x"
    t.integer "y"
    t.string "color"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.boolean "captured", default: false
    t.index ["game_id"], name: "index_pieces_on_game_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer "sign_in_count", default: 0, null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.inet "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.inet "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

end
```

This is the error:

```
PiecesController pieces#show action should return success if the piece color matches the user color
    Failure/Error: expect(response).to have_http_status :success
      expected the response to have a success status code (2xx) but it was 404
    # ./spec/controllers/pieces_controller_spec.rb:48:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

This is the Controller spec:

```
RSpec.describe PiecesController, type: :controller do

  describe 'pieces#show action' do
    it 'should return success if the piece color matches the user color' do
      game = FactoryBot.create(:game)
      piece = game.pieces.active.find_by({x: 1, y: 2})
      sign_in game.user
      get :show, params: { id: piece.id }
      expect(response).to have_http_status :success
    end
  end
end
```

This is the Model spec:

```
RSpec.describe Piece, type: :model do
  describe '#piece_color_matches_user_color?' do
    it '#piece_color_matches_user_color? returns true if the piece color and user color match' do
      game = FactoryBot.create(:game)
      piece = game.pieces.active.find_by({x: 1, y: 2})
      user = game.user
      result = piece.piece_color_matches_user_color?(user)
      expect(result).to eq true
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Apologies, I left some parts of the controller commented out - `if @piece.game.white_player_id` should be commented out, and `if @piece.piece_color_matches_user_color?(current_user)` should not be commented out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great and well-described question!

With ActiveRecord, after it queries your database it maps each returned column to a public method inside itself; so there's nothing stopping you from accessing the column directly your controller — or any class.

Having said, you have an `after_create` callback in your `game.rb` which is assigning a `User#id` to your `Game#white_player_id`, but it's not saving that column. Changing it to `before_create :current_user_is_white_player` *should* get you on the right track.

Comment: Thank you, the tests are now passing now that I have implemented your suggestion. Thank you also for the insight!